# Трансляция нескольких видеороликов по порядку без задержек в одном плеере

Tags: javascript, python

Хочу реализовать трансляцию видеофайла размером в 10 гигов на сайте с быстрой загрузкой. Идея такая - нарезать видео файл на небольшие фрагменты. Получиться много видеофайлов mp4 одного видео.

Нужно транслировать все видео файлы по очереди так, чтобы между первым и последующими видео не было задержки - смотрелся как один ролик. Подскажите какие технологии можно применить?

Comment: Многопоточность, асинхронную загрузку.

Answer (score 1):

Hls или mpeg-ts . чтоб склеилось генерится плейлист. Все это можно сделать через ffmpeg, gsteamer или vlc. Кладешь в папку нарезанное, плейлист в плеер и все играет без питона и без задержек.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!